# Как изменить автотекст в \section в LaTeX?

Tags: latex

С Latex'ом только знакомлюсь. Роюсь в интернете уже третий день и нервы уже на пределе.
Смысл в том, что при `\documentclass{report}`, когда действует команда `\section{}` ставится автоматический номер, например, "1.1". У меня есть требование, что этот номер должен быть оформлен как "1.1.".
Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это опция зависит не от класса документа, а от пакета, который отвечает за проверку языка - `babel` или `polyglossia`.

Если использовать последний с русским языком, то точки в заголовках ставятся автоматически (их наоборот, нужно убирать специальной опцией).

А вот с `babel` не подскажу - не знаю, как себя ведёт этот пакет.

Готовое решение будет примерно такое - включить в преамбулу следующие команды:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=true]{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа, если необходимо убрать точку - заменить значение в опции на false
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа
```

ВНИМАНИЕ! Точка пропадёт или появится не только с заголовков, но и с нумерации картинок и таблиц.